# Is there a way to move n files from n folders each folder contain 1 file with the same extension i.e (.pdf)

Tags: file, ubuntu, unix

i have 126 folders in the same directory with names like this
"5d843c63-2043-499b-abd6-6ea0bbde5f58"

each folder contain 1 #pdf file
i want to move each file to one

i have used the command and managed to locate all the pdfs in the separated folders
`locate ~/Desktop/wps\ /*pdf`

then i used the " | " to move them at once but i couldn't i use the commnad
locate ~/Desktop/wps\ /*pdf | mv ~/Desktop/pdffff/
STOUD be like `mv: missing destination file operand after '/home/yousef/Desktop/pdffff/'` 
using ubuntu

Comment: To clarify, you're trying to take several files from different folders and move them all into one folder?

Comment: Yes!, and your two methods works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the locate command, but if it returns a list of paths of the files you want, do

`` mv `locate ~/Desktop/wps\ /*pdf` /path_to/new_folder_to_store_pdfs ``

The backticks `` ` ` `` will execute the `locate` command first, then the output of `locate` will be substituted into the outer `mv` command.

I did it just now with find and it worked.

`` mv `find -name *pdf` new_folder ``